# Hypothetical: Is the interstellar wormhole too close to the black hole?

Tags: interstellar

Most reasonings about hypothetical wormholes say, that you need an extreme amount of energy to keep them open.

Given that, isn’t the worm hole too close to the black hole gargantua? The gravity between the two would make the spin and eventually collapse together?

Comment: Are you talking about the movie *Interstellar*?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because purely hypothetical

Comment: Yes the interstellar movie

Comment: This seems like more of a question for the Worldbuilding stack exchange.